# Xcode 5.1.1 expected identifier or '('

Tags: iphone, xcode

it says when i try and run my app that I need a expected identifier or '(' for this line of code:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
```

it is in this line of code:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
if(![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]){
    [self alert:@"PhotoLibrary is not supportted in this device."];
    return;
}
    imagePicker = imagePickerPhoto;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
else{
    if(!popover){
        imagePicker = imagePickerPhoto;
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }else{
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [popover release]; popover = nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please copy and paste from XCode, and enclose your code in 'code brackets'

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if(![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        [self alert:@"PhotoLibrary is not supportted in this device."];
        return;
    }
    imagePicker = imagePickerPhoto;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    else
    {
        if(!popover) {
            imagePicker = imagePickerPhoto;
            popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
            [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        }
        else {
            [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            [popover release];
            popover = nil;
        }
```

Looks like your first 'else' is in the wrong place, and you're missing a closing }